# Use Laravel Spark's Controllers/Actions in my app's API

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing, laravel-spark

I'm up and running with Laravel Spark, but I'd like to pull some of the user auth methods (and later, some others) in to my API.

Spark's default registration method is a `POST` request to `/register` that calls `Auth\RegisterController@register`.

I would like registration to be `POST` request to `api/v1/register` but for the sake of simplicity, I'd like to simply call Spark's `Auth\RegisterController@register` method.

I did try simply copying the RegisterController from Spark in to my app's controller directory, but that didn't seem like an elegant solution and it didn't work anyway.

My `app\Http\api.php` contains the following group:

```
Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'api/v1',
    'middleware' => 'auth:api'
], function () {
    Route::get('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm');
    Route::post('register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');
});
```

I'd love input and advice on the best way to pull in some of those Spark methods that I get out of the box.

Thanks in advance!